# XSL - How to select all ancestors upto the root, but not the sibling nodes

Tags: xslt, nodes, siblings

I have an xml payload

```
<Root>

    <Header>
        <Name>B</Name>
    </Header>
    <Item>
        <Id>10</Id>
        <Description>Item10</Description>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Id>20</Id>
        <Description>Item20</Description>
    </Item>
    <Package>
        <Id>A</Id>
    </Package>
    <Package>
        <Id>B</Id>
    </Package>
    <Package>
        <Id>C</Id>
    </Package>
</Root>
```

For each Package, I am trying to get output of the entire message of all ancestors of the current Package upto its root, but not its following sibling nodes (other packages).

Desired Output:

`

```
<Root>

    <Header>
        <Name>B</Name>
    </Header>
    <Item>
        <Id>10</Id>
        <Description>Item10</Description>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Id>20</Id>
        <Description>Item20</Description>
    </Item>
    <Package>
        <Id>A</Id>
    </Package>

</Root>
<Root>

    <Header>
        <Name>B</Name>
    </Header>
    <Item>
        <Id>10</Id>
        <Description>Item10</Description>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Id>20</Id>
        <Description>Item20</Description>
    </Item>

    <Package>
        <Id>B</Id>
    </Package>

</Root>
<Root>

    <Header>
        <Name>B</Name>
    </Header>
    <Item>
        <Id>10</Id>
        <Description>Item10</Description>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Id>20</Id>
        <Description>Item20</Description>
    </Item>

    <Package>
        <Id>C</Id>
    </Package>
</Root>
```

`

But I am getting 3 messages including all packages in each.

Here is my code

```
<?xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

<xsl:template match="/">
<Messages>
        <xsl:for-each select="//Package">
            <xsl:copy-of select="/*[not(following-sibling::*)]" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Messages>
</xsl:template>
```

What I am doing wrong? Thank you for your advice.

Comment: The only ancestor of a `Package` is its parent `Root`. Both `Header` and the `Item` elements are its siblings.

Answer (score 0):

To get the result you show (not the result you describe), you could do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <xsl:variable name="common" select="*[not(self::Package)]" />
    <xsl:for-each select="Package">
        <Root>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$common"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </Root>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

But do note that this result is an XML fragment, not a well-formed XML document, because it lacks a single root element.

Comment: Thank you. Here is the corrected input payload

`
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<Root>
    <Header>
        <Name>B</Name>
    </Header>
    <Item>
        <Id>10</Id>
        <Description>Item10</Description>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Id>20</Id>
        <Description>Item20</Description>
    </Item>
    <Packages>
        <Package>
            <Id>A</Id>
        </Package>
        <Package>
            <Id>B</Id>
        </Package>
        <Package>
            <Id>C</Id>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Root>
`

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. And changing your question after it has been answered is also not welcome. Still, the change is minor and I believe you should be able to make the necessary adjustment yourself.

Comment: Sorry about that. Will do. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

This statement doesn't do what you think it does:

```xml
<xsl:copy-of select="/*[not(following-sibling::*)]" />
```

That XPath expression begins with a `/` which is an absolute reference to the root of the document. So the result of the expression doesn't depend on the context node (a `Package` element) which has been established by the enclosing `xsl:for-each` iterator.

What the expression actually returns is the root element `/*`, so long as it has no following sibling elements (which is always true by definition since an XML document must have exactly one root element).

Hence the stylesheet simply returns several copies of the entire input document, one for each iteration of `//Package` in the document.